Why does the constructor of a non-private inner member class need a variable representing the immediately enclosing instance of this class?
I am very curious about this question. The Java Language Specification has told me part of the reason：


In a class instance creation expression for a non-private inner member class, §15.9.2 specifies the immediately enclosing instance of
the member class. The member class may have been emitted by a compiler
which is different than the compiler of the class instance creation
expression. Therefore, there must be a standard way for the compiler
of the creation expression to pass a reference (representing the
immediately enclosing instance) to the member class's constructor.
Consequently, the Java programming language deems in this section that
a non-private inner member class's constructor implicitly declares an
initial parameter for the immediately enclosing instance. §15.9.3
specifies that the instance is passed to the constructor. ...


But for me, this is still not detailed enough.
For example, why is it that because of "The member class may have been emitted by a compiler which is different than the compiler of the class instance creation
expression.", so "there must be a standard way for the compiler
of the creation expression to pass a reference (representing the
immediately enclosing instance) to the member class's constructor."?
I can't figure out what causal relationship exists between these two sentences.
I have read some related texts, such as this one and this one.But I still feel puzzled.
Could someone please explain this passage to me in detail?
It would be even better if an example could be combined.
Thank you for your reading.

An inner (non-static) class has the seemingly magical ability to reference the creating instance of the outer class, but it's actually just syntactic sugar. The compiler produces a normal class with an extra reference to the outer class passed into the constructor.
So what looks like this:
class Outer {
    class Inner {}
}

Effectively compiles to something like this:
class Outer {
    final Outer outer;

    static class Inner {
        Inner(Outer outer) {
            this.outer = outer;
        }
    }
}

Now, consider the caller:
Outer o = new Outer();
Inner i = o.new Inner();

This has to be translated by the compiler to:
Outer o = new Outer();
Inner i = new Inner(o);

But what if the inner class already has explicit constructor args? Do we call new Inner(o, arg0, arg1, ..., argN) or new Inner(arg0, arg1, ..., argN, o)? If we could guarantee the class and its users are built by the same compiler, the answer would be, "Who cares? It's not exposed to the code anyway.*" But classes need to be binary compatible, which means compiler A might produce class Inner and compiler B might produce the bytecode that's using it, and B needs to know how to pass in Outer when instantiating Inner. Hence the JLS specification that it's to be inserted as the first constructor argument.
*except via reflection, but let's not go there

Well, I know that the javac command can produce bytecode files. But what is meant by "produce class"?

In addition, I probably understand what you mean. My understanding is that you have explained why it is necessary to specify where to implicitly declare a reference to the outer class. But I still want to know why an inner class needs a reference to the outer class.As the specification says "The rationale for why only this kind of class has an implicitly declared constructor
parameter is subtle. The following explanation may be helpful:...".Thanks.

javac produces .class files representing classes compiled to bytecode. As for the outer reference, do you understand the difference between a static nested class and an inner class? The latter can reference the outer instance that created it, which means it must be stored somewhere on the inner instance.

I understand what you said.But the specification does not explain it in this way.By reading the first reason of specification 8.8.1, it seems to attribute the reason why an inner class needs a reference to the outer class to "The member class may have been emitted by a compiler which is different than the compiler of the class instance creation expression.", and the reason why an anonymous class does not need a reference to the outer class to " The local/anonymous class is necessarily emitted by the same compiler as the class instance creation expression.".

The specification does not say that the reason is that an inner class can reference an instance of an outer class.I cannot understand why the reasons given by the specification would lead to whether an inner class needs a reference to the outer class.

It's not giving a reason for the reference. That's self-explanatory and applies to both inner classes and anonymous classes. Rather, it's explaining why the implicit constructor argument needs to be part of the Java spec. In the case of anonymous classes, it's up to the compiler to determine how to capture the reference, as per the Who cares? logic in my answer. It's only the inner class which can be instantiated externally that has to be concerned about cross-compiler compatibility.

I think I understand.However, I still find it confusing what the specification is trying to explain in this part.[...]

It says " why only this kind of class has an implicitly declared constructor parameter is subtle. " before. This means that the following content is to explain why the inner class needs to implicitly declare additional parameters.[...]

But, according to your answers and what it says "Therefore, there must be a standard way for the compiler
of the creation expression to pass a reference (representing the immediately enclosing instance) to the member class's constructor.", it is more like the inner class by default needs an implicit parameter as an instance of the outer class for no reason. Instead, it turns to explain how the inner class needs to implicitly declare additional parameters (for example, the additional parameter that the inner class needs to implicitly declare is in the first position).

It's explaining both why and how. Why: binary compatibility. How: by an implicit initial parameter.

In my understanding (based on your answer), binary compatibility is the reason why a standard way is needed to indicate the position of implicit parameters, but it is not the reason why implicit parameters are needed. The specification should explain the latter, but it doesn't.Perhaps my understanding is incorrect?

Seems we're going in circles. Sorry I couldn't help.

Suppose there is no such requirement on how the enclosing instance is passed, and suppose that there are compiler implementations A and B.
Let's use compiler A to compile
public class Outer {
    public void foo() {

    }
    public class Inner {
        public Inner(Outer anotherOuter) {
            // Inner should be able to access the members of the enclosing instance here
            // Note that this is different from anotherOuter.foo()
            Outer.this.foo();
        }
    }
}

$ javacA Outer.java

This produces two files - Outer.class and Outer$Inner.class. Compiler A has put the anotherOuter parameter as the first parameter of the Inner constructor, and uses the second parameter to take the enclosing instance.
Then we use compiler B to compile
public class JavaClass
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Outer o1 = new Outer();
        Outer o2 = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner i = o1.new Inner(o2);
    }
}

# assuming Outer.class and Outer$Inner.class are on the class path
javacB JavaClass.java

But compiler B has a problem, what parameter should it pass to the constructor of Outer.Inner? From its perspective, Inner's constructor takes two Outer parameters, but it doesn't know which one is supposed to take the enclosing instance o1, and which one is supposed to take o2!
This is why the spec needs to specify this, essentially providing a way to identify which parameter should the enclosing instance be passed to.
Of course, it doesn't have to be the first parameter. This is just a design choice. The spec could have said that "the parameter with the name of <insert some name here> should be passed the enclosing instance" or many other variations.

Thank you. You have explained why it is necessary to stipulate where to implicitly declare a reference to the outer class. But I still want to know why an inner class needs a reference to the outer class.As the specification says "The rationale for why only this kind of class has an implicitly declared constructor
parameter is subtle. The following explanation may be helpful:...".

@user24723440 What do you mean by "why"? The language is designed so that you can access the enclosing instance in an inner class. If it doesn't have a reference to the outer class, how would you be able to access the enclosing instance? Having access to the enclosing instance is the main difference between an inner class and a static member class.

@user24723440 By the way I cannot find where the quotes come from. Please state which section of the spec they come from so we are on the same page.

My quotes are from 8.8.1, above the three reasons it gives. By reading the first reason of specification 8.8.1, it seems to attribute the reason why an inner class needs a reference to the outer class to "The member class may have been emitted by a compiler which is different than the compiler of the class instance creation expression.", and the reason why an anonymous class does not need a reference to the outer class to " The local/anonymous class is necessarily emitted by the
same compiler as the class instance creation expression.".

I cannot understand why the reasons given by the specification would lead to whether an inner class needs a reference to the outer class.

@user24723440 You grossly misunderstood what it says. In all cases an inner class needs a reference to its enclosing instance. The difference between a public inner class and an anonymous class is about how the enclosing instance is passed through the constructor. For a public inner class, the way that the enclosing instance is passed must be specified in the spec (namely, that the enclosing instance is the first parameter), because other compilers might need to call it. On the other hand, how enclosing instances are passed to anonymous classes need not be specified in the spec...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
